# Cómo saber si una persona es menor a 15 años

Tags: mysql, sql

Esta es la consulta con la que obtengo la edad real de las personas

```
SELECT  
    FLOOR ( DATEDIFF( CURDATE(),SUBSTRING(TRIM(CURP),5,6))/365) AS EDAD_REAL   
FROM `tbl_name`
```

pero no se como hacer para obtener si  hay personas que tienen 15 años

Comment: Hola Juan. Puedes añadir ejemplos de datos en tu tabla, lo que actualmente saca esa consulta y el comportamiento deseado?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Y aclara que base de datos estas usando. esa consulta para sacar una diferencia de años es bastante confusa

Comment: porque no usas un where luego del from : SELECT  
    FLOOR ( DATEDIFF( CURDATE(),SUBSTRING(TRIM(CURP),5,6))/365) AS EDAD_REAL   
FROM `tbl_name` WHERE EDAD_REAL <= 15.

Answer (score 0):

Deduzco que estás utilizando MySQL, por tanto con un Case puedes resolver tu tema

```
SELECT 
      FLOOR ( DATEDIFF( CURDATE(),SUBSTRING(TRIM(CURP),5,6))/365) AS EDAD_REAL,
    CASE 
       WHEN FLOOR ( DATEDIFF( CURDATE(),SUBSTRING(TRIM(CURP),5,6))/365) > 15 
         THEN 'Mayor'
       ELSE 'Menor'
   END EsMayorQue15
FROM `tbl_name`
```

Comment: Elena, es mejor esperar a que aclare la pregunta y asi no tienes que deducir nada. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM `tbl_name` 
WHERE FLOOR ( (SYSDATE-CAMPO_FECHA_NACIMIENTO)/365) = 15
```

El conteo arrojará la cantidad de personas que tienen la edad de 15 años

Comment: No es mejor esperar a que OP termine de aclarar la pregunta? y los años bisiestos?